# Javascript - change variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, button, twitter

I'm trying to build a page which will have a scrolling list of Twitter search results (using twitter.search for jQuery). The user should be able to change the search term by clicking a button (so, clicking "Apple" will change the search term to "Apple".

I'm using a variable to set the search term. Setting that variable to a text string (i.e. searchText = "Pineapple";) works. But when I try to change the variable using the buttons, nothing happens.

//edit - the button doesn't seem to change the variable. Thoughts? Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//set default value for searchText
    searchText = "Pineapple";

//this sets up our Twitter stream
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#twitter-stream').twitterSearch({ 
        term: searchText, 
        // no fade 
        animOut: { opacity: 1 }, 
        avatar:  false, 
        anchors: false, 
        bird:    false, 
        colorExterior: 'white', 
        colorInterior: 'white', 
        pause:   true, 
        time:    false, 
        timeout: 2000 
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button-container").on("button", "click", function( e ) {
        searchText = $(this).text();
    });
</script>
```

```
<div id="twitter-stream" title="Mouse away to un-pause">
</div>

<div id="button-container">
<button class="button"> Apple </button>
</div>

<button onclick="alert(searchText);">Click me!
</button>
```

Comment: instead of using a variable, why not use a hidden field and set the hidden field value to what you were setting the value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is very inefficient, you can use jQuery to define one function that handles *all* click events for the buttons, as opposed to 4 nearly identical functions.

Delegate your events using jQuery's `.on`:

```
$("#someContainerDiv").on("button", "click", function( e ) {
    searchText = $(this).text();
});
```

This eliminates the need for an array of values, as you just take the innerText of the button itself.

**References**

Here is some info on jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and here is some info on the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function it replaces.

Comment: Or a bit different, like this: 
$('.button').click(function(){        
      searchText = $(this).attr('id'); 
});
<button class="button" id="apple">
Apple
</button>

But it comes down to the same thing

Comment: The only thing to be weary of here is that `.click` does not handle event binding in the same way as `on`. If you bind a a function to an element using `click`, remove it, and reinsert it, the event will no longer be bound. Unlikely case in this example, but a big problem in larger web apps. Just food for thought.

Comment: Absolutely true, nice thought. Indeed probably not an issue for TS, but it's always good to have things like this in the back of your mind.

Comment: Thank you both, so much!

Still having a bit of trouble, though - I've updated my question.

Comment: Oops. Tweaked it a bit and now working. My fault. Thank you, again.